# jekyll serve --watch command raising an error outside of vagrant

Tags: vagrant, jekyll

Attempting to build a site with Jekyll using the jekyll-assets gem, I noticed that my changes were not being auto regenerated despite using the --watch flag on my jekyll serve command. Was a big headache having to stop the server every time I wanted to see changes in the browser so I tried to troubleshoot the problem and after a while learned that auto regeneration will not occur with the jekyll serve --watch command in Vagrant, which I'm using.

To avoid this headache I attempted to install necessary dependencies outside of Vagrant and jekyll serve --watch but am getting the following:

```
Configuration file: /Users/jamestargett/Code/jekyll_fingers/_config.yml
/Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-assets (LoadError)
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/jamestargett/Code/jekyll_fingers/_plugins/ext.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `each'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `block in setup'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `each'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `setup'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:29:in `initialize'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:5:in `new'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:5:in `process'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-1.4.2/bin/jekyll:97:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:66:in `run!'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
from /Users/jamestargett/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I've tried googling the problem but am pretty new to web development and a little lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also faced this problem. Looks like its a bug in the newest Jekyll 1.4.2 build. A fix can be uninstalling Jekyll 1.4.2 and installing a stable release, in my knowledge which is 1.2.1

Uninstall Jekyll and reinstall Jekyll 1.2.1 by following these commands

```
~ $ gem uninstall jekyll
~ $ gem install jekyll --version(="1.2.1")
```

Running `gem install jekyll -v 1.2.1` would also work